# Is having a wrapper for your IoC a good idea?

Tags: dependency-injection, structuremap, ioc-container, wrapper, abstraction

I have been using StructureMap for more than a year now. And all this time I used to have a wrapper class called IoC which looked like this

```
class IoC {
    public static T GetInstance<T>()
    {
        return (T)GetInstance(typeof(T));
    }
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetAllInstances<T>()
    {
        return ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances<T>();
    }

    public static IEnumerable GetAllInstances(Type type)
    {
        return ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances(type);
    }

    public static object GetInstance(Type type)
    {
        return ObjectFactory.GetInstance(type);
    }

    public static void Inject<T>(T obj)
    {
        ObjectFactory.Inject(obj);
    }
}
```

I added the wrapper assuming that I might want to change the IoC container at some point down the line. At this point I am thinking this is bad. One reason is: I cannot use ObjectFactory in my code to do other interesting things, I have to use this wrapper. The other thing is: Our code shouldn't really have to be independent of the DependencyInjection container.

What are the pros/cons of using this approach?

Comment: [Mark Seemann](http://blog.ploeh.dk/) calls such wrapper a 'Conforming Container'. He recently wrote a [blog post about this](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/conforming-container/) and he explicitly calls this an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this reason the [Common Service Locator](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com) project has been developed. It is an abstraction over DI frameworks and it defines an interface much like your `IoC` class. I even developed the [Simple Service Locator](http://simpleservicelocator.codeplex.com) library; an DI library that is a direct implementation of the Common Service Locator interface.

So in that sense, it's not weird to have an abstraction over DI frameworks. However, when doing Dependency Injection correctly (and completely), the idea is to adjust the design of your application accordingly, configure the container in the application root, and have preferably just a single place in the application were types are assembled (read: were `GetInstance` is called). For an ASP.NET MVC application, this would be the `ControllerFactory`. For ASP.NET WebForms application you would typically need to override a [PageHandlerFactory](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=81).

When you play by these rules, there is no reason to use such an abstraction, because you just call the container at a single place in your application anyway. However, if that's not feasible for you, using either the [Common Service Locator](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com) or your own abstraction is an alternative.

But please take a step back before you decide to let your code depend on an abstraction over your IoC library, because this causes a lot of problems and [is seen as an anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) in general. Calling back into the container from within your code:

- Makes the code much harder to test.
- Hides dependencies instead making the code harder to read and maintain.
- Disables compile-time support.
- Disallows your dependency graphs to be verified by a tool.

Comment: It makes sense to use wrappers around external dependencies, But, I don't know if there have been any real instances where people switch their IoC containers.

Answer (score 1):

The pro is that you can swap IOC containers painlessly. The con is that you lose any functionality specific to an IOC container. MVC turbine uses this approach. Have a look at it's source to see how it handles the locator. http://mvcturbine.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of libraries and a lot of applications built on top of those libraries you'll end up with a large amount of IoC registration code which gets duplicated across all of those applications.

You could have each library responsible for registering itself with a container but then it has to know about a specific IoC implementation. Or you could do as you suggest and create an IoC wrapper and have your libraries responsible for registering themselves via the IoC wrapper.